Select 2 , When no result Found Show a Button and open modal
I am trying to use Select2. When there is no searc result it is showing a Add button at below.
Image 1
Clicking on the add button opening the pop-up. So far it is good. But the select2 search box is coming on top of the modal.
Image 2
How can I hide the select2 search box when I am opening the pop-up?
Please guide. Thanks in advanced.
When I am trying to search item in select2 , it is working properly. But when no match found I am shoiwng a add button below. When clicking on the add button it should open a popup and hide the add button.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
